The Tarbell format
I'm reading this article by Don Tarbell about how to modify his cassette interface for higher speed. But I am mighty confused.
If I understand what he's doing here, he is increasing the oscillator from 3000 to 4800 Hz and then writing either 00000000 to produce a KC-standard 1, or 01010101 to produce a 0. But if that's 8 cycles at 4800, that would be 600 bps, not 300. The diagram on the first page suggests that 8 zeros produces 8 cycles at 2400 Hz, so I assume something in the hardware is doing a divide-by-two?
The article also states that the original Tarbell format is 187 bytes per second, which is dramatically faster than the KC format. I found a manual on archive.org, which suggests the basic format is 1500 bits er second, so that makes more sense at 3000 Hz. But I don't see any description of how that is written.
Can anyone clear this up? I'd be especially interested in a description of the Tarbell format itself, as it appears to be very different than KC.

“The Tarbell format” what?

Wikipedia describes the encoding fairly well: Tarbell Cassette Interface and if you also look at the article on Manchester code you can see why it was done that way.

Erm, isn't that twice the same link (for the manual) ? Also, isn't it using two bits to encode a cycle? (10/01 for 1/0) So an 8 bit output word creates 4 cycles on tape.

@Brian - yeah, after posting this I found another section in the manual that described it. Curious though, if this really worked at ~5400 bps, why didn't everyone use Manchester instead of FSK?
